# whitelist for html textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am looking for a whitelist for a textarea that would be used for titles of books. The only characters I want to allow are alphanumeric, spaces, hyphens, underscores, periods, and the `<br>` tag. Any other special characters should be converted to their htmlentities ideally. The page uses php, html, javascript, and jquery if that helps. Anyone have any ideas??

Example input in textarea:

```
<textarea>
I have this book called Sample- a Fake Book.    
</textarea>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Into which concrete problem did you run? And what is a "tag" character?

Comment: I used @orip first method of using htmlentities then bringing back the <br>'s. Worked fine for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this has any relation to security, i.e. making sure the data is always safe for display, then this must be done server-side.

Except for the `<br>` tag, just HTML-encoding should do what you want.

Probably the best way would be to use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and then bring the `<br>`'s back:

```
$encoded_text = htmlentities($input_text);

// replace the encoded <br>'s with the original <br>'s
$final_text = str_replace(htmlentities("<br>"), "<br>", $encoded_text);
```

Another way to try to get this behavior and still use `htmlentities` is to replace the `<br>` tags with a placeholder, run through `htmlentities`, then replace it back. Something along the lines of:

```
$br_placeholder = "XX_BR_PLACEHOLDER_XX";
$text_with_placeholders = str_replace("<br>", $br_placeholder, $input_text);
$text_with_htmlentities = htmlentities($text_with_placeholders);
$final_text = str_replace($br_placeholder, "<br>", $text_with_htmlentities);
```

Comment: thanks! the first method of bringing back the <br> tags worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow non-alphanumeric characters, but have them converted into htmlentities, then a whitelist isn't what you need. You can:

- use javascript and regular expressions to replace <, > and & before submitting
- let jQuery do the same thing using the `$('<div/>').text(string).html()` trick
- convert them on the server side in your PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Use an onkeyup handler on the textarea to detect when something's been entered. You then retrieve the textarea's content and check for 'illegal' characters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function textFilter() {
       this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-_\.]/, '');
    }

</script>

<textarea onkeyup="textFilter();"></textarea>
```

Not sure what you mean "the tag", so this function will not handle "tags". Note that this simply removes illegal characters, and does not convert them to char entities.

Comment: This removes the characters. They're supposed to be converted to html entities

Comment: It also doesn't stop people submitting malicious content via a custom post.